# CSV converted to int returns 0 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I am trying to convert a number from a csv file in order to query through my database.

Example row of the CSV input file:

> 40701620120093;TESTNAME;Testsurname;MALE;GROUPNAME;BSPK;;

What I'm doing in my Laravel `ListUploadController` is the following:

```php
while ( !feof($file) ) {
    $rawGroup = explode(";", fgets($file));
    $student = Student::where('skn', '=', $rawGroup[0])->get();
    $student->group = $rawGroup[4];
    $student->save();
}
```

I already tried explicitly converting to int by i.e.
Typecheck says that `$rawGroup[4]` is of type string.

`$skn = (int) $rawGroup[0];`

always returns

> $skn = 0

when I dd it. If it matters, in Excel I declared the original xls column as decimal and saved it as a CSV in UTF-8

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT 1:

```
print_r($rawGroup)
```

delivers

> Array ( [0] => 40701620120093 [1] => TESTNAME [2] => Testsurname [3] => MALE
>   [4] => GROUPNAME [5] => BSPK [6] => [7] => )

Comment: `print_r(rawGroup ); ` do this after second line and share the ouput

Comment: `$skn = (int) $rawGroup[0];` you mean?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo added, thanks.

Comment: @lagbox Of course, sorry. Fixed it

Comment: are you sure you have no spaces in column? try to `trim` value before casting into `int`

Comment: @RomanBobrik Tried that, after cast it still returns 0. Thanks anyways!

Comment: you can directly use update query instead of fetching it and setting it again. try this `Student::where('skn', '=', trim($rawGroup[0]))->get();`

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Tried it that way too, however it still returns an empty collection.. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Felix that means the row doesn't exist with these details